# Script for comments and rating AJAX

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

Is there any script which I can edit and insert into my CI... I want to be able to add comment and rating  and save it to database without reloading page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax call -> ci controller -> Controller verification -> Controller call to Model -> model handles db -> ci returns true/false back to ajax -> ajax handles accordingly.

**AJAX Call:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/index.php/ratings/process',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(data){
      console.log('your errors are: '+data.errors);
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log('added rating/comments to db!');
    }
});
```

**CodeIgniter Controller called ratings:** This doesn't have any form validation, you should probably do that. before calling this, or using a conditional statement to verify.

```
public function process(){
    $field1 = $this->input->post('field1', TRUE);
    $params = array( 'field1' => $field1);
    if (!$this->comments->addComments($params)){
      return $this->output->set_status_header(500, 'error submitting to db'); 
    }else{
      return $this->output->set_status_header(200, 'success!'); 
    }
}
```

**CodeIgniter Model called comments**

```
public function addComments($params = FALSE){
  // if params is not equal to false, do work.
  if (!$params == FALSE){
    //insert the params into the database comments
    $this->db->insert('comments', $params);
    // if affected rows is greater than 0, return the last inserted ID.
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
       return $this->db->insert_id();
    }else{
       // otherwise return false, fail
       return false;
  }else{
    // params were false so return false
    return false;
  }
}
```

Incomplete code, but you get the idea.

Comment: i don't use skype. You can conduct your questions on here.

Comment: well.. problem is that I don't know anything of AJAX...:/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7692/discussion-between-mike-and-bosnian)